# How to display pictures in page which are outside assets or public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a real huge app that among others stores pictures that are confident in some cases. So I cant store the pictures in the `public` or `assets` directory. But now I need to display some of the pictures in the page to authentificated users.

So how can I display Images in the page that are located out of the `public` or `assets` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **send_file** you can display image for protected images.with respective mime type and :disposition =>'inline'

Comment: and how do I use image_tag in combination with this?

Comment: Try image_tah(abc_path) in abc_path either pass asset id or some sort of identification for rendering image. in abc action find out image path and use send_file with mime and disposition inline